# Import NavLinks from different class to NavBar Class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey I am a beginner in React trying to make a navbar component using materialize css. I have two different classes for loggedinlinks and loggedoutlinks but when I import them in my Navbar class and run the app the links DO NOT show up. Please Help

Navbar

```
import { Component } from "react"
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Icon } from 'react-materialize';
import './navbar.css'
import Logo from '../assets/ptslogo.png'
import loggedinlinks from './signlinks/loggedinlinks';    /////<=it is also little darkened out in vscode

class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="navbar-fixed">
                <nav>
                    <div className="nav-wrapper black">
                        <Link to="/"><div className="logo left"><img className="logoimg" src={Logo} width="55px" alt="Platform Tech Solutions"></img></div></Link>
                        <span className="sidenav-trigger hide-on-large-only right" data-target="slide-out"><Icon>menu</Icon></span>
                        <loggedinlinks/>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Navbar;
```

loggedinlinks class

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'

class loggedinlinks extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <ul className="right">
                <li><NavLink className="white-text" to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink className="white-text " to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink className="white-text" to="/events">Events</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink className="white-text"  to="/register">Register</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink className="white-text"  to="/login">Login</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink className="white-text"  to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
export default loggedinlinks;
```

Comment: It seem totally fine. Maybe your path to component incorrect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react all custom components require a capital letter for the first letter of the component name. Therefore in this instance all you need to do is update you component to:

**Navbar**

```
<LoggedInLinks />
```

**LoggedInLinks**

```
class LoggedInLinks extends React.Component { /* logic goes here */ }

export defualt LoggedInLinks;
```